# Linq Lambda Where clause with in a where clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to build a lambda expression with serval where clauses with in each other.

Items, webProperties and profiles are all lists. I am trying to find the one that contains a profile which is 3 level lists down.  Actually all I am really trying to do is validate that it does exist.

```
 var x = AccountSummeriesResponse.items.Where(wp => wp.webProperties.Where(p => p.profiles.Where(a => a.id == profile ))).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting the following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'bool'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The probelm is [Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) returns `IEnumarable<T>` but the predicate of `Where` expects a boolen. You can use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:-

```
var x = AccountSummeriesResponse.items
           .Where(wp => wp.webProperties.Any(p => p.profiles.Any(a => a.id == profile )))
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, you can replace the Where with FirstOrDefault like this:-

```
 var x = AccountSummeriesResponse.items
         .FirstOrDefault(wp => wp.webProperties.Any(p => p.profiles
                                               .Any(a => a.id == profile )));
```

Comment: You Sir are my hero I tried playing with any and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because delegate(`Predicate`) inside the where clause needs to return bool and you are returning IEnumerable(`Where(p => p.profiles.Where(a => a.id == profile ))`) so reporting a compilation error.

Instead make a use of `Any` extension method if you are looking for whether exist in the collection kind of thing..

```
var x = AccountSummeriesResponse.items.Where(wp => wp.webProperties.Any(p => p.profiles.Any(a => a.id == profile ))).FirstOrDefault();
```